# How can I use a variable inside of my request results to traverse data?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a request to an API and within that request, I'm inserting a variable. It works fine and I get my results however I need to traverse the results but the first part of the result after body is the dynamic part that I used in the call.

I've already tried inserting the variable using template literals to traverse the body.

```
const symbols = argv.sym;

request(
  {
    url: `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=${symbols}&types=quote,chart&range=1d&chartInterval=30`,
    json: true
  },
  (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body, undefined, 2));
    console.log(`Company is: ${body.symbols.quote.companyName}`);
  }
);
```

First `console.log` works fine, however, the second `console.log` where I'm trying to traverse the dynamic symbol fails.

Example JSON results here:

https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=atvi&types=quote,chart&range=1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution. You didn't traverse the JSON correctly.

```js
const symbols = "atvi";

fetch(`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=${symbols}&types=quote,chart&range=1d`)
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>{
  console.log(data[symbols.toUpperCase()].quote.companyName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly using fetch. I couldn't get it to work with request though even with your suggestion of transforming the body into a new variable.